# Create a new string from an old one

Tags: c++, windows, string, pointers, copy

I'm using C++  (Windows environment). I have a :

```
LPCWSTR mystring;
```

This works :

```
mystring = TEXT("Hello");
```

But how to do this ? :

```
mystring = ((((create a new string with text = the content which is in another LPCWSTR 'myoldstring'))))
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

PS :

```
mystring = myoldstring;
```

would work , but it would not create a new string, it would be the same pointer. I want to create a new string !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LPTSTR mystring;
mystring = new TCHAR[_tcslen(oldstring) + 1];
_tcscpy(mystring, oldstring);

... After you are done ...

delete [] mystring;
```

This is a complete program

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    LPCTSTR oldstring = _T("Hello");

    LPTSTR mystring;
    mystring = new TCHAR[_tcslen(oldstring) + 1];
    _tcscpy(mystring, oldstring);

    // Stuff

    delete [] mystring;


}
```

It compiles fine with `cl  /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE a.cpp`

I used `tchar` macros. If you don't want to use it, then

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    LPCWSTR oldstring = L"Hello";

    LPWSTR mystring;
    mystring = new WCHAR[wcslen(oldstring) + 1];
    wcscpy(mystring, oldstring);

    // Stuff

    delete [] mystring;


}
```

Compiles fine with `cl a.cpp`

Comment: `error C2440: '=' : impossible de convertir de 'LPCWSTR *' en 'LPCWSTR'`

I am very very unlucky today !

Comment: @JosBas small error in my code - Corrected it - won't give this error.

Comment: the line with new LPCWSTR !

Comment: An error again :( :  `error C2664: 'wcscpy' : impossible de convertir le paramètre 1 de 'LPCWSTR' en 'wchar_t *'`

Comment: Did you do the 2nd change I have indicated - mystring should be `LPTSTR` or `LPWSTR` not `LPCWSTR`

Answer (score 2):

To use C++ standard strings, you need to include the `<string>` header. Since you're dealing with `LPCWSTR` (emphasis on the `W` part of that) you're dealing with wide characters, so you want to use wide strings (i.e., `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() { 
    LPCWSTR x=L"This is a string";

    std::wstring y = x;
    std::wcout << y;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but with this solution, there is crash !

Comment: @JosBas: That would point to a problem with the standard library you're using, or somewhere else in your code. Of the two, a problem elsewhere in your code seems a lot more likely to me. I've edited in a slightly more complete example that should compile and display the copied string (it does for me anyway). If it works, your problem is probably elsewhere in your code.

Comment: If I remove this line, no crash. If I add it, there is a crash. I have used another variable names that are used *nowhere else*, such that the crash cannot come from anywhere else.

Comment: @JosBas: That sounds like fairly typical results from having undefined behavior: some seemingly unrelated change suddenly leads to a crash. Without seeing your other code, it's impossible to guess where it might have come from though. Of course, it *is* always possible your standard library is defective -- `std::wstring` probably isn't nearly as well tested as `std::string` (but it's still much more likely the problem is in your code).

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
string myNewString = std::string(myOldString);
```

Just using the copy constructor of the string library.

Comment: `'string' : identificateur introuvable !`   (Can't find `string`)

I use C++ (no .NET )

Comment: @JosBas `#include <string>` ... and then make sure the `std` namespace is properly used, either though prefixing (`std::string` was omitted in one of the two cases above) or through `using namespace std;`.